# Change value of input based on radio with same parent

Tags: jquery

I have a webform where I want to change the value of a text input based on a corresponding radio button selection. Rather than using IDs of every text input and radio button, I want to follow a simple pattern where the text inputs base their value on the radio buttons that share a (non-immediate) parent fieldset.

There is more than one way to accomplish this, but my strategy was to look for the radio button's nearest parental fieldset (the one that's also parental to the text input), search it for the correct text input, and change that text input's value.

Here is what I have so far, but it does not work:

```
jQuery('.big-container input[id$="-selector-1"]').change(function() {
    var parent = jQuery('.smaller-container input[id$="-selector-1"]').closest('fieldset');
    jQuery('parent').find('.fieldset-wrapper div:nth-child(2) input').val('1');
});
jQuery('.big-container input[id$="-selector-2"]').change(function() {
    var parent = jQuery('.smaller-container input[id$="-selector-2"]').closest('fieldset');
    jQuery('parent').find('.fieldset-wrapper div:nth-child(2) input').val('0');
});
```

HTML:

```
<fieldset class="big-wrapper">
    <div class="fieldset-wrapper">
        <fieldset class="medium-wrapper-1">
            <div class="fieldset-wrapper">
                <div>...</div> <!-- unimportant -->
                <fieldset class="smaller-container-1">
                    <div class="fieldset-wrapper">
                        <div>
                            <label>...</label>
                            <div class="form-radios">
                                <div class="radio-1-wrapper">
                                    <div class="input-label-wrapper">
                                        <input id="blahblahblah-selector-1">...</input>
                                        <label>...</label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="radio-2-wrapper">
                                    <div class="input-label-wrapper">
                                        <input id="blahblahblah-selector-2">...</input>
                                        <label>...</label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="text-input-X">
                            <label>...</label>
                            <input>...</input>
                        </div>
                        <div class="text-input-Y">...</div> <!-- parallel to .text-input-X -->
                        <div class="text-input-Z">...</div> <!-- parallel to .text-input-X -->
                    </div>
                </fieldset>            
                <fieldset class="smaller-container-2">...</fieldset> <!-- parallel to .smaller-container-1 -->
                <fieldset class="smaller-container-3">...</fieldset> <!-- parallel to .smaller-container-1 -->
                <fieldset class="smaller-container-4">...</fieldset> <!-- parallel to .smaller-container-1 -->           
            </div>
            </fieldset>                
        <fieldset class="medium-wrapper-2">...</fieldset> <!-- parallel to .medium-wrapper-1 -->      
    </div>                
</fieldset>
```

In case it is not clear, `input[id$="-selector-1"]` and `input[id$="-selector-2"]` are the radio buttons, and the regular input within `div.text-input-X` is the one I want to change.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you post your HTML markup?

Comment: Abbreviated HTML is above now. Thought it might be distracting to see the whole thing, but knock yourself out.

Comment: Could you clarify: In all the fieldsets, you only want the first text input field to get updated when the radio buttons change? And the only values that first text input can have is `0` or `1` (based on the chosen radio button)?

Comment: Note: `jQuery('parent').find(...)` should be `parent.find(...)`

Comment: Thanks for the note. With the update to `parent.find(...)`, now all text inputs update when any radio button is chosen. What I am trying to achieve is that for each `fieldset.smaller-container-#`, `input.text-input-X` updates to reflect the radio selection. I effectively have 20 or so `input.text-input-X`, each in its own `fieldset.smaller-cotainer-#`. For this section, possible values are only 0 or 1. Other sections have other possible values that correspond to radios with classes ending in `-selector-#` (so I could add additional change functions to handle those).

Comment: Is the markup subject to change? What I mean is: can you add attributes to the markup? If so, there might be an elegant way to solve your problem using one binding function.

Comment: Umm. I cannot change the markup of most elements directly, but every element has various classes and the inputs may already have the attributes you need. I would need more details. Remember that the markup above is simply abbreviated to help demonstrate the structure pattern. Radio buttons all have `type=radio` and a class of `.form-radio`; text inputs all have `type=text`, and a class of `.form-text`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's go step by step to make changes that would simplify and hopefully clarify the code to meet your goal(s).

**1:** You're using `jQuery`, but I'll be using the shorthand `$` - unless you have a good reason (i.e. worried about conflict), this will improve legibility.

```
$('.big-container input[id$="-selector-1"]').change(function() {
    var parent = $('.smaller-container input[id$="-selector-1"]').closest('fieldset');
    $('parent').find('.fieldset-wrapper div:nth-child(2) input').val('1');
});
```

**2:** Fix the incorrect parent reference (as mentioned in the comment above).

```
$('.big-container input[id$="-selector-1"]').change(function() {
    var parent = $('.smaller-container input[id$="-selector-1"]').closest('fieldset');
    parent.find('.fieldset-wrapper div:nth-child(2) input').val('1');
});
```

**3:** Next, instead of creating multiple bindings for each input element, we'll create one delegate binding to the closest common parent that's available on dom ready - in this case, that's the `.big-wrapper` container.  I've also updated the selector from `$-selector-1` to a more general `*-selector-` to capture all radio buttons.  You can read more about the advantages of using delegation in the `.on()` [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

```
$('.big-wrapper').on('change', 'input[id*="-selector-"]', function () {
    var parent = $('.smaller-container input[id$="-selector-1"]').closest('fieldset');
    $parent.find('.fieldset-wrapper div:nth-child(2) input').val('1');
});
```

**5:** Using clearer variable names (ex: `$fieldset` instead of `parent`) can help you as you're manipulating the jquery elements.  Also, notice that we're able to get the target text input field in a simpler way. Note: I like to prefix the variable with a '$' sign to indicate that it's a jQuery element/collection.

```
$('.big-wrapper').on('change', 'input[id*="-selector-"]', function () {

    var $radio = $(this),
        $fieldset = $radio.closest('fieldset'),
        $input = $fieldset.find(".text-input-X input"),
        value = $radio.prop('id'); // <-- just as an example instead of the '1'

    $input.val(value);
});
```

**Demo:** [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4e4eepof/2/)

I hope there is enough in here to help you get on the right track. Good luck.

---

**Update:**

If you can update the markup, you can set the `value` attribute of the radio input and use it to set the value of the text field to `$radio.val()`

**Demo:** [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4e4eepof/5/)

Comment: Thank you so much for all the help. I am following what you did and have inserted appropriate selectors into my script to get it working on my webform. The problem I have remaining is that the `value` variable is not simply one value, it would change depending on the selected radio button. I have tried changing `value` with a nested function using a series of if else statements, but I cannot get it right. Is that the right approach? I need to say, e.g., if `$radio`'s ID `$="-selector-1"`, `value = 1`, but if `$radio`'s ID `$="-selector-2"`, `value = 0`.

Comment: Have a look at the update to see how to set the value to whatever you want, since there is no predictable formula for what the values should be... but you need to have that data in the markup.

Comment: Don't think that will work in my case, but what you've posted so far is enough that I think I can modify it to work for me. Thanks for all your help.